# Can I have 2 shopping carts that take 2 separate currencies on one site?

Tags: wordpress

We are in the process of revamping our site. We market a product in the US and Europe. At first we wanted the two prices in the US dollar and UK pound to show side by side but hard coding in round numbers won't allow it. The developer has suggested duplicate .com and .uk sites where a sniffer recognizes the appropriate IP. My partners don't want to duplicate costs of 2 sites. So is it possible to have two separate shopping carts that take different currencies linked to one site?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plugin for ecommerce, or building your own? If you use a third-party solution, like WooCommerce, they usually offer a feature to support multiple currencies. For example http://www.woothemes.com/extension/currency-converter-widget/ And that one does live currency lookups so you don't have to have the prices hard coded.